# WindowsForm control as a parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, parameters

My question is simple.

I have a method within a class and I want this method to change the text in a `TextBox`.
The `TextBox` might change during runtime so I'm trying to find a way to pass the `TextBox`
control as parameter when I call the method.

Is this even possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like it would have been more efficient to just try it first on your own.

Comment: @Ed S  I did. if i didn't I wouldn't have asked my question here

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Then please tell us what you tried (sample code?), and what went wrong when you tried it.  It's a fairly simple thing to pass a text box to a method, so it's hard to imagine what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Then why didn't you post what you had tried? A `TextBox` is an object like any other, so if you know how to declare a method that takes an argument then you should be able to declare a method that takes a `TextBox` as an argument.  Point is, you are lacking information here.  Be specific. Saying things like "it doesn't work" is never helpful.

Comment: I was missing an Include statement and I thought that I had these objects already declared that's why it didn't work and that's why I asked myself if it was even possible to do it. I could not have said maybe is it an include statement i'm missing? Or else i would have answered my question myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course, it's absolutely possible... a control is an object like any other, so it can be passed as a parameter or stored in a variable

```
void SayHello(TextBox textBox)
{
    textBox.Text = "Hello world";
}

...

SayHello(textBox1);
```

Comment: that was my first guess but it's not working. 
What do I need to include on top ? I have these right now 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

Comment: You must import `System.Windows.Forms`, since it's where the `TextBox` class is declared

Comment: That's the part I was missing thanks a lot ! I'm new to this sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add little more to this :

1. You can pass any **class , Interface, delegate , struct**  to a method as parameter. In your scenario TextBox is a class so you can pass it to method as parameter.
2. When you pass any reference type (except string) to a Method , no cloning on the passed object is done and changes to passed object will reflect sent object.  e,g :

   ```
   void  Method1 ()
   {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ..do some opeartion on ds.....          
    Method2(ds);
    ..print details of ds
   }

   Method2(DataSet myds)
   {
    ..do something to ds
   }
   ```

   You will notice that in in Method1 after calling Method2 the dataset object ds is changed.
3. For case number 2 above to apply for value types, pass the parameters as **ref** :

   ```
     void Method2(ref int count)
     {
          count = count++;
     }
   ```

   Here if you pass any integer to this method then passed integer will result in change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the controls as an argument in the class you need to use their namespaces on the top 
such as ;

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myprojectnamespace
{
    class myClass
    {
        public void myMethod(TextBox mytex, RichTextBox searchStr)
        {
          // ..Codes Here
        }
}
```